# if else statement where the condition is to match with the subtext of a text

Tags: vba

I want my condition to hold true if I find the string "john" in my cell .. and the cell value could be Mr John or John Carter. And both these scenarios should give a true value to my condition.

I tried the below code. Didn't work:

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "Benchmark report " & "*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of `=` (equal) you can use `Like`:

```
If ActiveCell.Value Like "Benchmark report " & "*"
```

Lookup `Like` in the help documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "Benchmark report") > 0 Then
    'String found in cell value
End IF
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good option to try in the immediate window:

```
?instr(1,"John carter",lcase("JOHN"),vbTextCompare)>0
```

Then replace the hardcoded values with `ActiveCell` or other ranges.